# W.Rudin (1.22 decimals)

Tags: real-analysis

I am reading the book of Rudin "Principles of mathematical analysis". 
In 1.22 decimals he wrote: Let $x>0$be real. Let $n_0$ be the largest integer such that $n_0\leqslant x$ (Note that the existance of $n_0$ depends on the archimedian property of $R$).

I have some questions:
1) Why he write about natural number but he did not defines them?
2) How he uses archimedian property in existance of $n_0$?

Answer (score 3):

1) Isn't really answerable by anyone other than Rudin unless you can clarify what you want to know exactly (or what kind of answer you'd expect).

For 2) can you write down the Archimedian property and then first try to prove that for all $x>0$ there is some $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $n> x$?
This proves that the set $\{m \in\mathbb Z \mid m \le x\}$ is bounded above and thus has a maximal element. This element is the $n_0$ from your text. (It's also called the *floor* of $x$, denoted by $\lfloor x \rfloor$)

Comment: Set $\{n\in N: n>x\}$ is not empty by Archimedian property applying to $1$ and $x$ and its also bounded below. But its a subset of $R$. By theorem 1.19 in Rudin we got that this set has infimum in $R$. But we must show that this infimum is an element of $N$. Am I right?

Comment: @Pacman No. The non-emptiness of your set is already enough for our proof. (But it _has_ a minimum in $\mathbb N$: $\lceil x\rceil$, the ceiling of $x$.)

Comment: What is wrong? I do not understand you

Comment: @Pacman Sorry, I didn't read carefully enough. You can prove that $\{n\in\mathbb N \mid n > x\}$ is bounded below by $0$ (because $0\not> x$) and thus it has a minimal element (this has nothing to do with the infimum in $\mathbb R$) However, this is not of any value to our proof at hand. All that we need is $\{n\in\mathbb N \mid n > x\} \ne \emptyset$ wich is guaranteed by the A.P.

Comment: My approach about that set is bounded by $x$ is wrong?

Comment: Why it has minimal element?

Comment: @Pacman Because of the [well-ordering principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_principle).

Comment: Rudin didn't define the natural numbers and it produced problems

Comment: @Pacman There is an analogous thing for $\mathbb Z$. It says that every subset of $\mathbb Z$ wich is bounded above has a maximum and every subset bounded below has a minimum. If he didn't even define $\mathbb Z$, the problem you asked about makes no sense ;)

Comment: In this book absent well-ordering principle.

Comment: @Pacman Can you edit your question to include everything you can use as it stands in the book? (For example the exact formulation of A.P. is necessary; there also needs to be _something_ like the w-o p because you can't prove it without this, the existence of an infimum in $\mathbb R$ is insufficient unless you also know that for closed sets, the $\inf$ will be a $\min$)

Answer (score -1):

For me, it is acceptable to take as an axiom the following statement:

**Well-ordering principle**: Every non-empty subset of $\mathbb{N}$ has a minimum element.

You are correct that Rudin never stated this property explicitly. To be fair to Mr. Rudin though, page 1 states:

"We shall not, however, enter into any discussion of the axioms that govern the arithmetic of the integers, but assume familiarity with the rational numbers...."

Using the axiom above, we can return to the decimal representation issue. For $x\in{}\mathbb{R}^+$ we have the set $S:=\{z\in{}\mathbb{Z}\,\,\,\wedge{}\,\,\,x<z\}$. This set is non-empty by the archimedean property* therefore it has a minimum element $m_0$ by the well-ordering principle. Then $m_0-1=n_0$.

*The archimedean property furnishes a natural number $n$ such that $1\cdot{}n>x$. Thus $n\in{}S$ and $S\neq{}\varnothing{}$.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).